# "String.replace" does not work for unicode notations

Tags: javascript, typescript

I expect that the function `buildAllKindsOfSpaceCharactersSetExpression` will replace `\\u{2002}\\u{2003}\\u{2004}\\u{2005}\\u{2006}\\u{2007}\\u{2008}\\u{2009}` to `\\u{2002}-\\u{2009}`.
Why it does not happen?

```js
enum SpaceSymbolsRegularExpressionUnicodeNotations {
  regularSpace = "\\u{0020}",
  noBreakSpace = "\\u{00A0}",
  enSpace = "\\u{2002}",
  emSpace = "\\u{2003}",
  threePerEmSpace = "\\u{2004}",
  forPerEmSpace = "\\u{2005}",
  sixPerEmSpace = "\\u{2006}",
  figureSpace = "\\u{2007}",
  punctuationSpace = "\\u{2008}",
  thinSpace = "\\u{2009}",
  hairSpace = "\\u{200A}",
  zeroWidthSpace = "\\u{200B}",
  ideographicSpace = "\\u{3000}",
  zeroWithNoBreakSpace = "\\u{FEFF}",
  characterTabulation = "\\u{0009}"
}

function buildAllKindsOfSpaceCharactersSetExpression(
    exceptions: Array<SpaceSymbolsRegularExpressionUnicodeNotations> = []
): string {

  const desiredSpacesSet: Array<string> = [];
  for (const space of Object.values(SpaceSymbolsRegularExpressionUnicodeNotations)) {
    if (!exceptions.includes(space)) {
      desiredSpacesSet.push(`\\${space}`);
    }
  }

  return `[${Object.values(desiredSpacesSet).join("")}]`
      .replace(
          "\\u{2002}\\u{2003}\\u{2004}\\u{2005}\\u{2006}\\u{2007}\\u{2008}\\u{2009}",
          "\\u{2002}-\\u{2009}"
      );
}

console.log(buildAllKindsOfSpaceCharactersSetExpression()); // [\\u{0020}\\u{00A0}\\u{2002}\\u{2003}\\u{2004}\\u{2005}\\u{2006}\\u{2007}\\u{2008}\\u{2009}\\u{200A}\\u{200B}\\u{3000}\\u{FEFF}\\u{0009}]
```

### Experiments

Works:

```js
return `[${Object.values(desiredSpacesSet).join("")}]`
      .replace(
          "\\u{2002}",
          "FOO"
      );
```

Does not work!

```js
return `[${Object.values(desiredSpacesSet).join("")}]`
      .replace(
          "\\u{2002}\\u{00A0}",
          "FOO"
      );
```

Works:

```js
return `[${Object.values(desiredSpacesSet).join("")}]`
      .replace(
          "\\u{2002}\\",
          "FOO"
      );
```

Does not work!

```js
return `[${Object.values(desiredSpacesSet).join("")}]`
      .replace(
          "\\u{2002}\\u",
          "FOO"
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake:

```js
desiredSpacesSet.push(`\\${space}`);
```

Here is `\\` is not required.

And, as @zerkms prompted,

```js
desiredSpacesSet.push(space);
```

Comment: String literal is not required there either.